# Создание индекса для поиска GIN

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, search, index

Пытаюсь создать индекс в `PostgreSQL 11` для столбцов `title` и `text` в таблице с публикациями - заголовок и текст статьи соответственно следующей командой:

```sql
CREATE INDEX search_index 
ON publications 
USING GIN(
  (setweight(to_tsvector('title'), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('text'), 'B'))
);
```

Нужно для более быстрого поиска по этим полям (сейчас поиск занимает около 20 секунд).

Выдает ошибку :

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
SQL state: 42P17
```

Как решить? или может есть иной способ ускорить поиск слов по статьям и заголовкам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индексы действительно возможно создавать только если выражение отмечено как `immutable` - то есть для одного и того же аргумента функция будет возвращать повторяемые результаты.

Вам необходимо использовать другой `to_tsvector`. Всего их в штатной поставке 6 функций: 3 из них принимают один аргумент (соответственно типов `text`, `json`, `jsonb`) и опираются на настройку `default_text_search_config`. Вот как раз из-за зависимости от настройки они и не могут использоваться в индексах.

И есть другие 3 функции `to_tsvector`, принимающие два аргумента - имя конфигурации поиска и непосредственно данные. Они от настроек не зависят и их в индексе использовать можно.

```
CREATE INDEX search_index 
ON publications 
USING GIN(
  (setweight(to_tsvector('russian', 'title'), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('russian', 'text'), 'B'))
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!